# ShareActionProvider Shows two Icons A System Icon And A share Icon

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I am adding a Share Action Using the Code Below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.esir.jualeader.aspirant.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_finish"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Exit"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="Share"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
</menu>
```

and

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent){

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
private Intent createShareIntent(){
    Intent actionsend=new Intent();
    actionsend.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    actionsend.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Please Download Jua Leader App From :  http://mstarsinnovations.com");
    actionsend.setType("text/plain");
    return Intent.createChooser(actionsend,"Share The Jua Leader Using");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    // Return true to display menu
    return true;
}
```

The Result Is A Share Icon That Looks As Shown In The Image [image]

Why Is The Other Icon Appearing And It is the Only Clickable Icon.How Can I Remove It?
Any Help Will be Highly Appreciated.

Comment: What did you think a `ShareActionProvider` looks like? If you just want a share button, then you don't need a `ShareActionProvider`.

Comment: what Do I Need Exactly ??

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Just The Share Icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what a `ShareActionProvider` is supposed to look like. If you just want a share button, then stop using `ShareActionProvider`. I.e., update your XML to remove the `ShareActionProvider`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

(You'll need to add your own `@drawable/share` to your app such as one from the [material design icons](https://material.io/icons/)).

Then override your [onOptionsItemSelected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) method to start your share when the menu item is tapped:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch(item.getMenuId()) {
    case R.id.share:
      Intent shareIntent = createShareIntent();
      startActivity(shareIntent);
      return true;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

You don't need to do anything in `onCreateOptionsMenu` except inflating your menu.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html#rankings) make it very clear: "The share action provider retains a ranking for each share target, based on how often the user chooses each one. The more often a user chooses a target, the higher its rank; **the most-commonly used target appears in the app bar as the default target.**"

Comment: Thanks For the Clarification

Answer (score 0):

it shows that you have shared content with that app(icon shown right side to share icon) most recently.